# What is the source of BB area creaking associated with ambient temperature changes?

Tags: drivetrain

A general answer would be welcome, maybe encompassing -10C-40C/15-100F temperatures, but my particular ride is an aluminium frame with pressfit BB30 and Tiagra commponents, in Scotland's climate, stored outside but in a shed.

Last year I had a tiny bit of creaking/snapping from the bottom bracket/cranks, or at least it was at the same part of the pedal stroke each time. Through the winter when the temperature was generally 5-10C/40-50F it was pretty much silent, and this weekend it's started making a lot of noise again after the temperature ranged from about 0-15C/32-60F in the space of a few days.

There's not really anything else I can attribute the change to, I'm assuming there's a small amount of expansion/contraction in the metal parts which may not be uniform across each component - last weekend no noise, this weekend Creak-Clunk City.

Comment: Here's a Velonews Q&A on hydraulic disc brakes in the cold. Their performance can be affected substantially in sub-freezing conditions. Anyone else feel free to use this. https://www.velonews.com/gear/technical-faq-disc-brakes-cold-weather/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pressfit BBs are prone to creaking at the best of times. When cold, steel inside aluminium will be tighter than when warm, as the thermal expansion of aluminium is [about twice that of steel](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/thexp.html). The difference is only about 0.001% per degree C, but on something the size of a BB from a cold day to a warm one  that's around 0.1mm, easily the difference between a tight fit and one with some movement.